# How can I check if two sprites are overlapping/touching in Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'd like to determine if two sprites are overlapping in Monogame. I'd like to use a check similar to that below:

```
if ( /* Are Sprites Overlapping? */ )
{
    // Do stuff; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
 if (mySprite.Intersects(otherSprite))
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this works with other cases like `Rectangle` too.